# After updating colgroup template in Angular 16, the styles are not updated in broser

Tags: angular, frontend

I have an Angular application, which was migrated from 12 to 16. I changed width in my colgroup template, and now it is not rendering(was not working after migration)
but if I set it manually to .scss file, it works fine

Maybe there is some common solution for Angular?

I've checked on presence for all required attributes in apache config - Cache-Control no-cache, also tried to rename styles.scss, as well as adding --prod(is deprecated with Angular 16) to ng build, tried
ng build -configuration production --aot,
was adding:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
```

to index.html